# How to use Prettier in VS Code for any supported files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier

I want to be able to use a shortcut to format my documents, but it doesn't work with files like **.gitconfig** but works with **.js**-like files.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of what Prettier actually supports. The list of languages that Prettier supports formatting for can be found at https://prettier.io/docs/en/. At the time of this writing gitconfig files or files in a similar format are not supported.

If you want to configure what languages are formatted by the Prettier extension for VS Code, see [How to use prettier for specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68520304/11107541)